# Fourier series of $\csc^2(a\cdot z)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Looking at the Fourier series of the Weierstrass $\wp$ function, I have a term going like $\csc^2(az)$. A straightforward method to get its Fourier series is writing it like
$$
\csc^2(az)=\frac{4}{2-e^{2iaz}-e^{-2iaz}}.
$$
Mathematica returns the series
$$
\csc^2(az)\sim -\sum_{n=1}^\infty 4n e^{2inaz}.
$$
Could one make sense of this result or does it exist a known formula I am not aware of?

Comment: What do you mean by "Could one make sense [...]"? Are you looking for a proof/derivation of the series representation? Also, I am not sure what the "$\sim$" means in your question - should it be "$=$"?

Comment: The series is not converging so, I think it should be understood in the sense of distributions. Just to see if I can use it in some real computations.

Comment: I agree that it won't converge where the poles of $\operatorname{csc}(z)^2$ are, but it will converge for some other $z$ (I suspect it converges iff $\operatorname{Im}z> 0$).

Comment: My interpretation would be: The series makes sense wherever it converges. It would be interesting to see how it is derived, this might give a clue about its domain.

Comment: Does this come from the context of QFT? You might consider adding the appropriate tag to attract the right people. My above comments are from a purely (complex) analysis perspective.

Comment: @DominikS Thanks a lot for your help. It is a solution of the equation $\Box\phi=-a\phi^2+d$ provided a given dispersion relation holds. When you expand in Fourier series $\wp$ you will find this contribution to appear. My question was if the harmonics are the same.