# Closed form for the $n$-th derivative of $\csc^2$?

Tags: derivatives, closed-form

To find a closed representation for the $n$-th derivative of $f(t)=\csc^2(t)$, I started with the Ansatz:
$$
f^{(n)}(t) = \frac{p_n(\sin t, \cos t)}{\sin^{2+n}(t)} \tag1
$$
where $p_n$ is a polynomial (with integer coefficients) in two variables.
This leads to the recursion
$$
p_{n+1}=xy\frac{\partial p_n}{\partial x}
-x^2\frac{\partial p_n}{\partial y}
-(2+n)\,y\,p_n~;\qquad p_0=1 \tag2
$$
and I am stuck. Likely, someone has solved this before and has a pointer to the $n$-th derivative of $\csc^2$?

With *"closed representation"*, I mean something like a finite sum and without recursion.

---

Note: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1701540/746312) is on $\cot$ and only comes up with a recursion. (It's a polynomial in just 1 variable so maybe simpler to turn into an explcit form.)

---

**Edit**

That question leads to Lemma 2.1 in: V.S. Adamchik, [On the Hurwitz function for rational arguments](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2006.08.096), *Applied Mathematics and Computation*, Volume 187, Issue 1, 1 April 2007, Pages 3–12.

It states for the $n$-th derivative of $\cot z$, $n>1$:

$$
\frac{d^n}{dz^n} \cot z
= (2i)^n (\cot(z)-i)\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{k!}{2^k} \left\{ {n \atop k} \right\} (i\cot(z)-1)^k \\
$$

$$
\text{where } \left\{ {j \atop k} \right\} \text{ is the Stirling subset}\dots
$$

but after the $\dots$ the text is truncated

I cannot make 100% sense of it and how $k$ is computed etc. Maybe someone kows the missing bits.

Comment: surely it is convenient to pass to a series form of cotangent and differentiate *that* $(n+1)$ times.

Comment: I know that, but's an infinite series. That's where I am coming from.

Comment: The "question" you mention at the end of your text dealing with the nth derivative of "$\cot$" function (knowing that you need the (n+1)st derivative of $-\cot$)  gives you all the desirable answers...

Comment: @JeanMarie: My view of Lemma 2.1 is crippled. I added the bits I can see to the question, but I can't figure out the rest.

Comment: $ y=-1/ \sin^2 x,~\text{take logs} ~ \dfrac {y'}{y}=2 \cot x $;...can be implicit  continued $n$ times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(-\cot x)'=(\csc^2 x)$, so $(\csc^2 x)^{(n)}=-(\cot x)^{(n+1)}$ and we only have to find the $n$-th derivative of cotangent.

---

Since $\cot x=\frac1\pi \psi \left(1-\frac{x}{\pi }\right)-\frac1\pi\psi \left(\frac{x}{\pi }\right)$ (where $\psi$ is [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function)), its n-th derivative [is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-%5C%5BPi%5D%5E%28-1%20-%20n%29%20PolyGamma%5Bn%2C%20x%2F%5C%5BPi%5D%5D%20%2B%20%28-1%29%5En%20%5C%5BPi%5D%5E%28-1%20-%20n%29%20%20%20%20PolyGamma%5Bn%2C%201%20-%20x%2F%5C%5BPi%5D%5D)

$\cot^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^n \pi ^{-n-1} \psi ^{(n)}\left(1-\frac{x}{\pi }\right)-\pi ^{-n-1} \psi ^{(n)}\left(\frac{x}{\pi }\right)$

Wolfram Mathematica says [you can express it in cotangent functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cot/20/02/0003/):

$\cot^{(n)}(x)=(-2 i)^n (\cot (x)+i) \underset{k=0}{\overset{n}{\sum }}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k (i \cot (x)+1)^k k! \mathcal{S}_n^{(k)}$, where $S$ are the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

There are also [other formulas](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cot/20/03/).

---

Thus,

$(\csc^2 x)^{(n)}=(-1)^n \pi ^{-n-2} \psi ^{(n+1)}\left(1-\frac{x}{\pi }\right)+\pi ^{-n-2} \psi ^{(n+1)}\left(\frac{x}{\pi }\right)$

(in terms of polygamma function)

$(\csc^2 x)^{(n)}=-(-2 i)^{n+1} (\cot (x)+i) \underset{k=0}{\overset{n+1}{\sum }}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k (i \cot (x)+1)^k k! \mathcal{S}_{n+1}^{(k)}$

(in terms of elementary functions)

Mathematica code verifying the two formulas above:

```
n = 3;
Plot[{Evaluate[
   D[Csc[x]^2, {x, n}]], -(-2 I)^(
    n + 1) (I + Cot[x]) Sum[(-(1/2))^k (1 + I Cot[x])^
     k k! StirlingS2[n + 1, k], {k, 0, n + 1}], Pi^(-n - 2)
     PolyGamma[n + 1, x/Pi] + (-1)^n Pi^(-n - 2)
     PolyGamma[n + 1, 1 - x/Pi]}, {x, -10, 10}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> 10]
```

[image]

Comment: What's the meaning of superscript `(k)` for a Stirling number?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Comment: It mentions $S(n,k)$ as notation and $\{ {n \atop k} \}$, but not $S^{(k)}_n$. So are all three notations identical?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts yes

Answer (score 1):

Here is a closed form using a different approach. Applying the binomial theorem, $$(a+b)^{-2}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\binom{-2}ka^{-k-2}b^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)a^{-k-2}(-b)^k$$ to $\csc^2(x)=-\frac4{(e^{-i x}-e^{ix})^2}$ and again on $(k+1)^n$ gives:

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\csc^2(x)=-4\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{2i(k+1)x}= -4(2i)^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)^{n+1}e^{2i (k+1)x}=-4(2i)^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}mk^me^{2i (k+1)x}$$

Switching sums gives the following [Hurwitz Lerch transcendent](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HurwitzLerchPhi.html) solution:

$$\boxed{\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\csc^2(x)=-i^n2^{n+2}e^{2 i x}\sum_{m=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}m\Phi(e^{2 i x},-m,0)}$$

[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5Bcsc%5E2%28x%29%2C%7Bx%2C5%7D%5D%3Dsum%5B-%28I%5E5+2%5E%282+%2B+5%29+E%5E%28%282+I%29+x%29+Binomial%5B1+%2B+5%2C+m%5D+HurwitzLerchPhi%5BE%5E%28%282+I%29+x%29%2C+-m%2C+0%5D%29%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C5%2B1%7D%5D). However, [converting](https://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/LerchPhi/03/01/01/01/0008/) the Lerch transcendent into a [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), in software, gives the wrong result.

Comment: I am not sure to understand the why and how of what you call "complex version of $\csc^2$" and the formula thereafter. Can it be interpreted as a complex Fourier series ?  (see for example the discussion around [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4781250/305862)).

Comment: @JeanMarie Please see the edit